# Is there any way where we can see local storage data in android project in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-storage

Is there any option where we can see local storage data in the android project in android studio?
Like in Ionic we can see Local Storage as well as Session Storage from:

- ctrl + shift + I (Inspect)
- Select Application Tab
- On the left hand, you will find the **Local Storage** option there you will be able to see all your data stored in your local data.
  Do we have something like this in Android Studio for Android Projects?

Comment: If you want to see the data folder of your app where it also saves the SharedPref and Sqlite db, use the "Device File Explorer" tab at bottom-right of Android Studio.
Goto data->data->[your_apps_pkg_name]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Device File Explorer

- Press Shift twice
- Type Device File Explorer
- Enter

Tool Window will appear showing the file system of connected devices and allows to download and upload files.
[image: Android Studio Device File Explorer]